# Clarification on example from Ansible documentation needed

Tags: ansible

The [`lxd_container` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lxd_container_module.html) for Ansible 2.5 contains this example:

```
# An example for creating a Ubuntu container and install python
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Create a started container
      lxd_container:
        name: mycontainer
        state: started
        source:
          type: image
          mode: pull
          server: https://images.linuxcontainers.org
          protocol: lxd
          alias: ubuntu/xenial/amd64
        profiles: ["default"]
        wait_for_ipv4_addresses: true
        timeout: 600

    - name: check python is installed in container
      delegate_to: mycontainer
      raw: dpkg -s python
      register: python_install_check
      failed_when: python_install_check.rc not in [0, 1]
      changed_when: false

    - name: install python in container
      delegate_to: mycontainer
      raw: apt-get install -y python
      when: python_install_check.rc == 1
```

Could anyone explain to me why the example makes use of the [`raw` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/raw_module.html) instead of the [`apt` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html)?

Is this some kind of insider knowledge that was used here and (prematurely?) optimizes how Ansible performs, based on the `ansible_connection=lxd` versus `ansible_connection=ssh` for `mycontainer` or something?

After all it's be much simpler to dispose of these last two tasks in favor of:

```
- name: install python in container
  delegate_to: mycontainer
  apt: pkg=python state=latest
```

... of course with the option to update the apt cache and all that.

So why resort to the `raw` module here?

NB: I am asking this mainly because usually the documentation shows the canonical way of doing things. But from what I understand, canonically I am supposed to use the specific modules such as `apt` rather than invoking `shell` or `raw` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I found the reason.

So Ansible will *normally* generate a Python (2.x) script to execute on the remote machine via whatever connection method is configured for any particular host.

Alas, Python is a prerequisite of the `apt` module. The `raw` module does not seem to have this limitation and therefore can be used to install the prerequisites required to run Ansible tasks on the (remote) hosts, using `dpkg` and `apt-get` commands directly on the remote system. By the way, the `shell` module has the very same limitation, but the `raw` module does not. I wish this would have been mentioned a little more explicitly in the documentation, though.

In this case the result dictionary contains a key named `module_stderr` with the following value: `module_stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\n`. Make it visible by increasing the verbosity when invoking `ansible-playbook`.

Now that I know what's going on, this sentence from the `raw` module documentation makes a whole lot more sense:

> This module does not require python on the remote system, much like the [script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/script.html) module.

I did not find this earlier, because I was incrementally running my playbook, so the `python` package was already installed when I thought to myself "why not use the `apt` module?"